# Visual Studio copying DLL's to build directory even if i'm not referencing them

Tags: c#, .net

I've made a class library.

It has the following references.
[image: references]

I've set the Copy to Local property of all references all dll's refered to false.
So I'm expecting only ModuleB.dll in the build directory.

[image: Build Folder]

I'm not directly referring some of the dll's that's in the builder.

What am i missing ?

## EDIT 1

It's a .NET Framework class library
I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: What kind of library is this? .NET Framework, .NET Core, or .NET Standard?

Comment: it is .NET framework

Comment: This is what happens when one of the libraries you reference targets .NETStandard.  They are glue to make such a library work on old .NETFramework versions.  Changing the project's framework target to 4.7.2 tends to solve it.  Or by using an older version of the library.